# How to debug a project with Output Type of Class Library in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I ran into a problem that I need to debug inside a method of class library project? But I received an project errors said "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly"?
Is there a way to work around this? My project is a user control.

```
 [XRDesigner("Rapattoni.ControlLibrary.CCMLThreePicGalleryTableDesigner," + "Rapattoni.ControlLibrary")]
    public class CCMLThreePicGalleryCtrl : XRTable
    {
        #region Variables
        const int cTableWidth = 825;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Get\Set  bindable variables
        /// </summary>

        [Bindable( true ), DesignerSerializationVisibility( DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden )]
        public string SerialPicUrlString
        {
            get
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }
            set
            {
                SetPictures( value );
            }
        }

        private int CellWidth
        {
            get;  
            set;
        }

        private int CellHeight
        {
            get;  
            set;
        }

        private int PicHeight
        {
            get;  
            set;
        }

        private int PicWidth  
        { 
            get; set; 
        }

        private int MaximumPictures
        {
            get; set;
        }
        #endregion Properties


        #region Events

        #endregion

        #region Public/Private Methods

        private void SetPictures( string urlString )
        {
            CellWidth = 275;
            CellHeight = 130;
            PicWidth = 175;
            PicHeight = 120;
            //CommentCellWidth = "150";
            MaximumPictures = 12;

            this.Rows.Clear();
            this.BeginInit();

            string[] urls = urlString.Split( ';' );

            XRPictureBox picBox;
            XRTableRow row;
            CCMLThreePicGalleryCell cell;  //, CommentCell;

            // Prepare first Row
            row = new XRTableRow();
            row.Height = CellHeight; 
            row.CanShrink = false;

            int picTotal = urls.Length;
            /*
            if (picTotal % 3 == 1)  // Don't have one picture in a row
                picTotal--;
             */
            if (picTotal > MaximumPictures)      // Max of 12 pictures shown
                picTotal = MaximumPictures;
            else if (picTotal == 1)
                picTotal = 0;

            // Keep track of which picture
            int picCount = 0;
            // Go through each picture and assign to a cell
            for (int i = 0; i < picTotal; i++)
            {
                if (urls[i] != "")
                {

                    if (picCount % 3 == 0 && picCount > 0 )   // Make a new row after every 3rd picture
                    {
                        // Create a new row for pictures
                        row = new XRTableRow();
                        row.Height = CellHeight;
                        row.CanShrink = false;
                    }


                    cell = new CCMLThreePicGalleryCell();
                    cell.Size = new Size(CellWidth, CellHeight);
                    cell.CanShrink = false;
                    cell.Padding = new PaddingInfo(0, 0, 5, 5);


                    //CommentCell = new ThreePicGalleryCell(); // Don't want Comments

                    string[] url_comment = urls[i].Split('|');
                    picBox = new XRPictureBox();
                    //picBox.HtmlItemCreated += new HtmlEventHandler(picBox_HtmlItemCreated);
                    picBox.Sizing = ImageSizeMode.ZoomImage;
                    url_comment[0] = url_comment[0].Trim();
                    picBox.ImageUrl = url_comment[0];
                    picBox.Size = new Size(PicWidth, PicHeight);

                    cell.Controls.Add(picBox);

                    row.Cells.Add(cell);

                    if (picCount % 3 == 0)   // Add Finalized row
                    {
                        this.Rows.Add(row); // Add current row

                    }
                picCount++;
                } 
            }
            // Fix for odd bug where final picture is out 
            // of alignment if it is 2nd in the last row 
            if (picCount % 3 == 2)
            {
                cell = new CCMLThreePicGalleryCell();
                cell.Size = new Size(CellWidth, CellHeight);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
                this.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            else if (picCount % 3 == 1)  // When last row has 1 picture
            {
                this.Rows.Remove(row);
            }


            if (urlString.Equals(string.Empty))
                this.Rows.Clear();

            this.EndInit();

        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you write a test harness? Maybe a console application.
Class Libraries are not executable and therefore cannot be started directly for debugging. The debugger can only attach to running processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically I'd create a separate unit test class library project, and then start *that* in whatever your favourite unit test runner is, and debug that way.

Alternatively, start debugging whatever application would actually *use* your class library, exercise functionality which will hit whatever breakpoint you want to set, and go on from there.

Answer (score 3):

Setup a second small project to consume the library.

Comment: Jon Skeets Unit test style project is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the Visual Studio debugger to the process in which the binary is running.

Comment: I'm not sure how to achieve this. Do you have any reference?

Comment: Debug menu -> Attach to Proccess

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jon Skeet. TDD (Test-driven development) is the best way to go for Service or Business Logic oriented classes.

It allows you to launch small portion of the GUI and test it without loading the whole app.

Comment: please change "DTT" to "TDD"